# PHP Calendar: next available timeslots

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, calendar

**Context:**

I'm building a webapp which is mainly based on the scheduling function of a calendar. I chose fullcalendar.io to display the events and have therefore created a rather simple mysql structure:

```
id (autoincrement)
patient_id (the users id)
start (datetime, e.g. 2016-04-06 14:30:00)
end (datetime)
```

Now the challenge that I'm trying to solve is to find available timeslots for a given day...
That being said, there a few more variables which make it more complex:

- session_length (int) is the duration in minutes which is given by the user's settings
- session_interval (int) is the interval between two sessions.

So if `session_length = 45 & session_interval = 15`, we're looking for a timeslot of 75min.
If a timeslot is a multiple of 75, we need that one to be added to the `$available_timeslots array()`.

**What I tried :**

Of course, putting the events scheduled for that day into an array called `events` :

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [title] = Client 24
            [start] = 2016-04-06 21:15:00
            [end] = 2016-04-06 22:30:00
        )

    [1] = Array
        (
            [title] = client 1
            [start] = 2016-04-06 16:40:00
            [end] = 2016-04-06 17:55:00
        )

)
```

And various loops based on more creative than effective code, like testing through a loop of 1440 minutes (= 1 day) which ones are overlapping with an event. That seems incredibly heavy but is the best solution I have so far.

**How I want to use the available slots:**

The idea is to display them in a modal having a list of the 10 (or 20) next available dates using the following html template:

```
<ul class="available_dates">
    <li class="date" data-start="_TIMESLOT_STARTDATE_" data-end="_TIMESLOT_ENDDATE">Monday - 06/04/2016 09:30</li>
    <li class="date" data-start="_TIMESLOT_STARTDATE_" data-end="_TIMESLOT_ENDDATE">Monday - 06/04/2016 10:45</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions are welcome, I tried thousands of things but can't find a reliable and lightweight solution to my problem.

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: One suggestion: instead of start and end times in the table, maybe start time and duration. I believe that will make the math much easier when you pull out all the scheduled events and run the loop to check for conflicts.

Comment: 1) get the duration isn't that heavy... And 2) I don't see how that might help - could you elaborate ?